# Gantt style time line plot (in base R)

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
       person n start end
1         sam 6     0   6
2        greg 5     6  11
3     teacher 4    11  15
4         sam 4    15  19
5        greg 5    19  24
6       sally 5    24  29
7        greg 4    29  33
8         sam 3    33  36
9       sally 5    36  41
10 researcher 6    41  47
11       greg 6    47  53
```

Where start and end are times or durations (sam spoke from 0 to 6; greg from 6 to 11 etc.).  n is how long (in this case # of words) the person spoke.  I want to plot this as a time line in base R (I eventually may ask a similar question using ggplot2 but this answer is specific to base R [when I say base I mean the packages that come with a standard install]).

The y axis will be by person and the x axis will be time.  Hopefully the final product looks something like this for the data above:

[image: Timeline_Graph]

I would like to use base R to make this.  I'm not sure how to approach this.  My thoughts are to use a dot plot and plot a dotplot but leave out the dots.  Then go over this with square end segments.  I'm not sure about how this will work since the segments need numeric x and y points to make the segments and the y axis is categorical.  Another thought is to convert the factors to numeric (assign each factor a number) and plot as a blank scatterplot and then go over with square end line segments.  This could be a powerful tool in my field looking at speech patterns.

I thank you in advance for your help.

*PS the argument for square ended line segments is* `segments(... , lend=2)` *to save time looking this information up for those not familiar with all the segment arguments.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While the y-axis is categorical all you need to do is assign numbers to the categories (1:5) and track them.  Using the default as.numeric() of the factor will usually number them alphabetically but you should check anyway.  Make your plot with the xaxt = 'n' argument.  Then use the axis() command to put in a y-axis.

```
axis(2, 1:5, myLabels)
```

Keep in mind that whenever you're plotting the only way to place things is with a number.  Categorical x or y values are always just the numbers 1:nCategories with category name labels in place of the numbers on the axis.

Something like the following gets you close enough (assuming your data.frame object is called datf)...

```
datf$pNum <- as.numeric(datf$person)
plot(datf$pNum, xlim = c(0, 53), type = 'n', yaxt = 'n', xlab ='Duration (words)', ylab = 'person', main = 'Speech Duration')
axis(2, 1:5, sort(unique(datf$person)), las = 2, cex.axis = 0.75)
with(datf, segments(start, pNum, end, pNum, lwd = 3, lend=2))
```

Comment: very nice.  That does pretty near what I asked for (within the base parameter) and I can take it from here.  Very nice work.

Comment: I hope you don't mind, but I slipped the piece of code `, lend=2` into your `segments` use.

Comment: Care to add image of the result?

Answer (score 31):

You say you want a base R solution, but you don't say why. Since this is one line of code in `ggplot`, I show this anyway.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(colour=person)) + 
    geom_segment(aes(x=start, xend=end, y=person, yend=person), size=3) +
    xlab("Duration")
```

[image]

Comment: it sounds like he's avoided all other outside dependencies for a package he's developing, and is trying to keep it that way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9857787/collapse-columns-by-grouping-variable-in-base.

Comment: He also might want more control of the appearance, to understand base graphics better, to integrate it with other base graphics plots, or just have a preference.  Oh, and this isn't really one line.  You have minimally 2 lines there, easily interpreted as 3, and you forgot install.packages('ggplot2').

Comment: @Andrie, that is very nice.  The reason I don't want to use ggplot is as Chase notes, I have avoided all dependencies except wordcloud (as this package does some coding in C I am not capable of doing).  That being said the function will plot but will also return a processed data frame that can be fed to ggplot (I plan on showing this as an example in my package though may have to use `#` to get the code to pass the package creation tests.  The reason I'm interested in ggplot is because I will use the same idea for repeated measures and faceting will be nice here.  Great work Andrie. +1

Comment: @TylerRinker Nice one. You have two options to include this in a package without introducing a dependency. 1) Use a `dontrun` block http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#index-g_t_005cdontrun-76 2) Use `suggests(ggplot2)` in your package `DESCRIPTION` and then `require(ggplot2)` in your example. In this way, the `ggplot2` package only gets loaded if the user actually wants to use it.

Comment: @Andrie Thanks this is my first package for general consumer use (I've created 2 packages for myself before but am being as disciplined as I can for a first timer) and want to provide as quality of a product as I can.  Thank you for the dependencies vs suggests info +1

Comment: Hi there, is there anyway to add text labels on the bars?

Answer (score 17):

Pretty similar to @John's approach, but since I did it, I will post it :)

Here's a generic function to plot a gantt (no dependencies):

```
plotGantt <- function(data, res.col='resources', 
                      start.col='start', end.col='end', res.colors=rainbow(30))
{
  #slightly enlarge Y axis margin to make space for labels
  op <- par('mar')
  par(mar = op + c(0,1.2,0,0)) 

  minval <- min(data[,start.col],na.rm=T)
  maxval <- max(data[,end.col],na.rm=T)

  res.colors <- rev(res.colors)
  resources <- sort(unique(data[,res.col]),decreasing=T)

  plot(c(minval,maxval),
       c(0.5,length(resources)+0.5),
       type='n', xlab='Duration',ylab=NA,yaxt='n' )
  axis(side=2,at=1:length(resources),labels=resources,las=1)
  for(i in 1:length(resources))
  {
    yTop <- i+0.1
    yBottom <- i-0.1
    subset <- data[data[,res.col] == resources[i],]
    for(r in 1:nrow(subset))
    {
      color <- res.colors[((i-1)%%length(res.colors))+1]
      start <- subset[r,start.col]
      end <- subset[r,end.col]
      rect(start,yBottom,end,yTop,col=color)
    }
  }
  par(mar=op) # reset the plotting margins
}
```

Usage example:

```
data <- read.table(text=
'"person","n","start","end"
"sam",6,0,6
"greg",5,6,11
"teacher",4,11,15
"sam",4,15,19
"greg",5,19,24
"sally",5,24,29
"greg",4,29,33
"sam",3,33,36
"sally",5,36,41
"researcher",6,41,47
"greg",6,47,53',sep=',',header=T)

plotGantt(data, res.col='person',start.col='start',end.col='end',
          res.colors=c('green','blue','brown','red','yellow'))
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: This answer also fulfilled the parameters I listed.  It looks terrific as well.  Thank you for sharing, a slightly different approach. +1

Comment: Also thank you for the word Gantt as well.  I didn't know what it was called.

Comment: @TylerRinker: You're welcome :). However I slightly changed the code to make space for the labels.

Comment: I want to include some of this work in a package.  I want to properly cite you.  Can you please contact me @ tyler.rinker@gmail.com

Comment: @TylerRinker: thanks but there's no need to cite me for this little piece of code. Feel free to use it ;)

Comment: @digEmAll - hi, I have a follow-up question regarding how to plot categories on the y when they exist in the whole df but not in a subset you're plotting, and also the ability to consistently use colors for particular y-axis categories.   I posted a question on this here-   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26374327/gantt-plot-in-base-r-modifying-plot-properties  - hope you can help. thanks.