# How to add multiple line segments between two associated points in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some sequence feature information I want to visualize. 
Here is some toy data(the specific r code to regenerate the data is at the end)

```
          type index variable position
...
14         CDS    14    start 31129
15        exon    15    start 32196
16         CDS    16    start 32196
17  stop_codon    17    start 32247
18        exon     1      end 12166
19         CDS     2      end 12166
...
```

The command I used to generate the following plot is

```
qplot(position,type,data=m2data,color=type)+xlim(11950,15000)
```

[image: what I have so far]

But I want to add the line segments between "start" and "end" that share the same "index"
like following, which I made with the paint.

[image: What I want]

How can I achieve this with ggplot2 in R?

The following is the data

```
m2data<-structure(list(type = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L), class = "factor", .Label = c("CDS", 
"exon", "start_codon", "stop_codon")), index = c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", 
"16", "17", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", 
"11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17"), variable = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), .Label = c("start", "end"), class = "factor"), position= c(11955L, 
12026L, 12026L, 16677L, 16677L, 17745L, 17745L, 17787L, 18309L, 
28587L, 28658L, 28658L, 31129L, 31129L, 32196L, 32196L, 32247L, 
12166L, 12166L, 12028L, 16841L, 16841L, 17814L, 17786L, 17789L, 
18898L, 28798L, 28798L, 28660L, 31299L, 31299L, 32270L, 32246L, 
32249L)), .Names = c("type", "index", "variable", "position"), row.names = c(NA, 
-34L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Gantt style time line plot (in base R)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9862519/gantt-style-time-line-plot-in-base-r)

Comment: I actually asked the same question in base but Andrie gave an excellent ggplot2 answer.  I think you may want to start with reshaping your data set from long to wide.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a solution to your problem. Although your question is quite similar to a previous one, I think that providing an answer specific to your data set is still useful.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

# Use dcast (in reshape2 package) to create separate columns for start and end.
dat = dcast(m2data, type + index ~ variable, value.var="position")

plot_1 = ggplot(dat, aes(x=start, xend=end, y=type, yend=type, colour=type)) +
         geom_segment(size=3) +
         geom_point(size=3) +
         geom_point(aes(x=end), size=3)

ggsave(filename="plot_1.png", plot_1, width=10, height=2.5)
```

[image]

Comment: super! exactly what I was looking for.
Btw, I guess you can pass the xend and yend params in aes in ggplot() rather than geom_segment()?

Comment: Glad to help! I find it most convenient to map all aesthetics in the initial `ggplot()` call. But sometimes that isn't sufficient, as with my two calls to `geom_point()`. The first implicitly uses `aes(x=start)`. But in order to also add the end points the second call to `aes()` is needed.

Comment: Thanks for this very nice answer and good looking graph! This is also exactly what I needed.