# Collapse all columns by an ID column

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to do something similar to [what's answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9857787/collapse-columns-by-grouping-variable-in-base), which gets me 80% of the way. I have a data frame with one ID column and multiple information columns. I'd like to roll up **all** of the other columns so that there's only one row for each ID, and multiple entries are separated by, for instance, a semicolon. Here's an example of what I have and what I want.

HAVE:

```
     ID  info1          info2
1 id101    one          first
2 id102   twoA second alias A
3 id102   twoB second alias B
4 id103 threeA  third alias A
5 id103 threeB  third alias B
6 id104   four         fourth
7 id105   five          fifth
```

WANT:

```
     ID          info1                          info2
1 id101            one                          first
2 id102     twoA; twoB second alias A; second alias B
3 id103 threeA; threeB   third alias A; third alias B
4 id104           four                         fourth
5 id105           five                          fifth
```

Here's the code used to generate those:

```
have <- data.frame(ID=paste0("id", c(101, 102, 102, 103, 103, 104, 105)),
                   info1=c("one", "twoA", "twoB", "threeA", "threeB", "four", "five"), 
                   info2=c("first", "second alias A", "second alias B", "third alias A", "third alias B", "fourth", "fifth"),
                   stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
want <- data_frame(ID=paste0("id", c(101:105)),
                   info1=c("one", "twoA; twoB", "threeA; threeB", "four", "five"), 
                   info2=c("first", "second alias A; second alias B", "third alias A; third alias B", "fourth", "fifth"),
                   stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9857787/collapse-columns-by-grouping-variable-in-base) asked basically the same question, but only a single "info" column. I have multiple other columns and would like to do this for all of them.

Bonus points for doing this using dplyr.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here's an option using `summarise_each` (which makes it easy to apply the changes to all columns except the grouping variables) and `toString`:

```
require(dplyr)

have %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(toString))

#Source: local data frame [5 x 3]
#
#     ID          info1                          info2
#1 id101            one                          first
#2 id102     twoA, twoB second alias A, second alias B
#3 id103 threeA, threeB   third alias A, third alias B
#4 id104           four                         fourth
#5 id105           five                          fifth
```

Or, if you want it separated by semicolons, you can use:

```
have %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(paste(., collapse = "; ")))
```

Comment: Dammit.  Haha you posted this while I was editing my deleted answer.

Comment: That's SO life ;-) @RichardScriven

Comment: It's rough in this hood.  This beats mine anyway since I didn't know about `paste(., collapse = "; ")`  I just wrote a custom `paste`.  Still learning `dplyr`

Comment: Thanks. Mick's solution below also works well. This solution takes about 12 seconds, the solution below using base takes about 14 seconds, for collapsing 43,602 rows to 41,128.

Comment: Welcome, @StephenTurner - seems both solutions are pretty close to each other then.

Comment: how many seconds does it take you to load dplyr

Comment: It's always loaded :) -- @rawr

Comment: toString did not come to my mind. My breakfast note is this one. Nice! +1 :-)

Answer (score 12):

Good old `aggregate` does this just fine

```
aggregate(have[,2:3], by=list(have$ID), paste, collapse=";")
```

Question is: does it scale?

Comment: +1 for the base R solution

Comment: cleaner than mine: `do.call(cbind, lapply(names(have[-1]), function(ii) by(have, have$ID, FUN = function(x) paste(x[[ii]], collapse = '; '))))`

Comment: The formula method is a bit cleaner `aggregate(. ~ ID, have, paste, collapse = "; ")` and might be faster

Answer (score 10):

Here's a `data.table` solution.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(have)[, lapply(.SD, paste, collapse = "; "), by = ID]
#       ID          info1                          info2
# 1: id101            one                          first
# 2: id102     twoA; twoB second alias A; second alias B
# 3: id103 threeA; threeB   third alias A; third alias B
# 4: id104           four                         fourth
# 5: id105           five                          fifth
```

Comment: Is this your first data.table answer? +1 :-)

Comment: @jazzurro - Thanks.  I think it's my second or third.  I'm learning it all!!

Comment: @RichardScriven I see. I am learning data.table too. I wrote two answers with data.table so far. I can often read codes, but writing is still a bit different story. I gotta catch up!

Comment: @jazzurro I agree. `data.table` is really nice, but also much different than what I'm accustomed to.  I'm going through the intro pdf right now.  Hopefully I'll add a few more DT answers soon :-)

Comment: @RichardScriven Cool. I have the CRAN manual. I also try to take one example from here everyday and take notes. Seeing David's and akrun's works is helping me quite a bit.

Answer (score 4):

Here is **SQL** solution^1:

```
library(sqldf)
#Static solution
sqldf("
SELECT ID,
       GROUP_CONCAT(info1,';') as info1,
       GROUP_CONCAT(info2,';') as info2
FROM have
GROUP BY ID")

#Dynamic solution
concat_cols <- colnames(have)[2:ncol(have)]
group_concat <-
  paste(paste0("GROUP_CONCAT(",concat_cols,",';') as ", concat_cols),
        collapse = ",")
sqldf(
  paste("
      SELECT ID,",
      group_concat,"
      FROM have
      GROUP BY ID"))

# Same output for both static and dynamic solutions
#      ID         info1                         info2
# 1 id101           one                         first
# 2 id102     twoA;twoB second alias A;second alias B
# 3 id103 threeA;threeB   third alias A;third alias B
# 4 id104          four                        fourth
# 5 id105          five                         fifth
```

^1 - probably `data.table` solution would perform better with millions of rows, luckily we don't have that many genes yet :)

Comment: Is there a way to do this for all columns witzig explicitly writing the code for each (as indicated in the question there are many columns to be collapsed)?

Comment: @beginneR updated the post with dynamic solution, this is where the code gets ugly...

Comment: The dynamic version could also be written using `fn$` like this: `nms <- names(have)[-1]; grp <- toString(sprintf("group_concat(%s, ';') as %s", 
                     nms, nms)); fn$sqldf(
      "SELECT ID, $grp
      FROM have
      GROUP BY ID")`

Comment: @G.Grothendieck nice one, never heard of `fn$`. How do one come across such hidden gems?

Answer (score 1):

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
have %>% tbl_df %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise_each(funs(str_c(., collapse="; ")))
```

Edit 1: So `tbl_df` may not needed and instead of the str_c of the `stringr` package you could use `paste` (in `base`). And what the above does is to group by the ID column and then apply the `str_c` (or `paste`) function to each remaining column for each group.

Edit 2: Another solution using the [data.table](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/) package:

```
library(data.table)
dtbl <- as.data.table(have)
dtbl[,lapply(.SD, function(x) paste(x,collapse=";")), by=ID]
```

The above may be faster, especially if you set the key:

```
setkey(dtbl, ID)
```

"Hybrid" solution: You can use the `dplyr` syntax for data.tables! For example:

```
dtbl %>% tbl_dt %>%
     group_by(ID) %>% 
     summarise_each(funs(paste(., collapse="; ")))
```

Comment: Some explanation would be useful.