# Collapse a character vector by value in another column r

Tags: r, plyr, tapply, split-apply-combine

I have a dataframe with a set of character strings in one column, and a grouping variable (a string, but could be a factor) in another.  I'd like to `collapse` the dataframe such that the strings are collapsed into elements by grouping-variable.  For info, I'm then going to use `Corpus(VectorSource(x))` on that vector (i.e., I'm collapsing to create documents).

So for example:

```
    eg           Type
1   tomato        F 
2   mushrooms     F
3   snow          W
4   chips         F
5   rain          W
```

This would be converted into a character vector with two elements, the members of 'W' and the members of 'F'.
I know I can use:

```
a <- paste(x$eg,collapse=" ")
```

To get all of them and of course just manually create subsets (or loop). 
I was wondering if there was a `plyr` function (but couldn't see one), and I think `tapply` or `by` might be what I'm looking for (in base) but I'm not clear how they'd be used here.

I'm not looking to output a dataframe here, but exploring the flagged duplicates clearly those methods apply to this question.

Comment: Other alternatives using `dplyr`, `data.table` etc [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26981385/r-collapse-all-columns-by-an-id-column/26981611#26981611)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer using data.table package:

```
> dt <- data.table(eg = letters[1:8], Type=rep(c("F","W"), 4))
> a <- dt[, paste(eg, collapse=" "), by=Type]
> a
   Type      V1
1:    F a c e g
2:    W b d f h
```

The bonus of using data.table is that this will still run in a few seconds even if you get up to millions of rows.

Comment: Thanks @Laurik I should explore data.table more

Comment: @sjgknight, you might find the [new vignettes](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/944) helpful (other vignettes in preparation).

Answer (score 1):

Just found an answer, this should work from the `plyr` package:

```
a <- vaggregate(x$eg,x$Type,function(y) paste0(y,collapse=" "))
```

**EDIT:** See comments below - the function(y) is superfluous, and this can be done from `base`

Comment: Or just `aggregate(eg ~ Type, x, paste0, collapse = " ")` from base ...

Comment: or `vaggregate(x$eg, x$Type, paste0, collapse=" ")`

Comment: Or with `dplyr`  `d %>% group_by(Type) %>% summarise(catY = toString(eg))`