# Concatenate strings by group with dplyr for multiple columns

Tags: r, string, data.table, dplyr, concatenation

Hi I need to concatenate strings by groups for multiple columns. I realise that versions of this question has been asked several times (see [Aggregating by unique identifier and concatenating related values into a string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16596515)), but they usually involve concatenating values of a single column.

My dataset is something like:

```
Sample  group   Gene1   Gene2   Gene3
A       1       a       NA      NA
A       2       b       NA      NA
B       1       NA      c       NA
C       1       a       NA      d
C       2       b       NA      e
C       3       c       NA      NA
```

I want to get it into a format where each samples takes only 1 row (the group column is optional):

```
Sample  group   Gene1   Gene2   Gene3
A       1,2     a,b     NA      NA
B       1       NA      c       NA
C       1,2,3   a,b,c   NA      d,e
```

Since the number of genes can go up to the thousands, I can't simply specify the columns that I wish to concatenate.
I know `aggregate` or `dplyr` can be used to get the groups but I can't figure out how to do it for multiple columns.

Thanks in advance!

### Edit

As my dataset is very large containing thousands of genes, I realised dplyr is too slow. I've been experimenting with data.table and the following code can also get what I want:

```
setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) paste(na.omit(x), collapse = ",")), by = Sample]
```

The output is now:

```
   Sample group Gene1 Gene2 Gene3
1:      A   1,2   a,b            
2:      B     1           c      
3:      C 1,2,3 a,b,c         d,e
```

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Are those `NA`s or empty strings (`""`)?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. They are NAs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For these purposes, there are the `summarise_all`, `summarise_at`, and `summarise_if` functions. Using `summarise_all`:

```
df %>%
  group_by(Sample) %>%
  summarise_all(funs(paste(na.omit(.), collapse = ",")))
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 3 × 5
>   Sample group Gene1 Gene2 Gene3
>    <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
> 1      A   1,2   a,b            
> 2      B     1           c      
> 3      C 1,2,3 a,b,c         d,e
> ```

---

Update: In current versions of `dplyr`, it is encouraged to combine `summarise` with `across`, e.g. like this:

```
df %>%
  group_by(Sample) %>%
  summarise(across(everything(), \(x) paste(na.omit(x), collapse = ",")))
```

Comment: Thank you both for your answers! However my dataset is very large and dplyr takes a long time to run.
I realised that my question can also be solved using data.table: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26981425/6782374.
However I do not know how to omit the NAs.

Comment: I found a way already and edited my question to reflect the code I eventually used. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

using `dplyr`, you can try:

```
dft %>%
  group_by(Sample) %>%
  summarise_each(funs( toString(unique(.))))
```

which gives:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 5
  Sample   group   Gene1 Gene2    Gene3
   <chr>   <chr>   <chr> <chr>    <chr>
1      A    1, 2    a, b    NA       NA
2      B       1      NA     c       NA
3      C 1, 2, 3 a, b, c    NA d, e, NA
```

Edit:
@Axeman had the right idea with using `na.omit(.)` to get rid of null values

Comment: summarise_each will be deprecated.